# Plot a the equation of a line with shading below

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

Is it possible to obtain something similar to what I show below with Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Basically, I started with `RegionPlot` and I continue with `Plot[-(2/3) x + 6, {x, -5, 15}, Filling -> Axis]`. But I cannot find how to better manipulate the filling option, let alone how to create this "randomly" looking region.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use the `RegionPlot` and add some additional condition on the region you want to show. For example:

```
Show[
  RegionPlot[
    2 x + 3 y < 6 && 
    Sqrt[0.9 (x - 1.2)^2 + (y - 1)^2] < 3 + 0.2 Sin[6 ArcTan[x - 1, y - 1]],
    {x, -3, 5}, {y, -3, 5}, 

    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    Frame -> False, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y},
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {-2, 4}}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False,
    ImagePadding -> 20,
    PlotPoints -> 40, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None],

  Plot[y /. Solve[2 x + 3 y == 6, y], {x, -1.45, 3.85}],
  Graphics[Rotate[Text[2 x + 3 y == 6, {1.3, 1.4}], -35 Degree]]
]
```

[image: Random region plot]

Of course choosing the clipping region may be the biggest challenge. Here I used equation for a circle, and added some wiggles with sine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to accept a shaded half-plane in place of an irregular region, it is relatively easy.

```
Module[{pts},
  pts = {x, y} /. FindInstance[2 x + 3 y == 6, {x, y}, Reals, 2];
  Graphics[
    {{GrayLevel[.8], HalfPlane[pts, {+1, -1}]},
     InfiniteLine[pts],
     Rotate[
       Inset[
         Style[TraditionalForm[2 x + 3 y == 6], 14], 
         .5 ({0, 2} + {3, 0}) + .2 {1, 1}], 
       ArcTan[-2/3]]},
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 5}, {-3, 5}},
    Axes -> True]]
```

[image: graphics]

#### Update

`Plot` and `Filling` and be used to do this, too. You simply have to use a different set of options.

```
Plot[2 - 2 x/3, {x, -4, 5},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-3, 5}},
  Filling -> Bottom,
  Epilog -> 
    {Rotate[
       Inset[
         Style[TraditionalForm[2 x + 3 y == 6], 14], 
         .5 ({0, 2} + {3, 0}) + .2 {1, 1}], 
       ArcTan[-2/3]]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your workaround. But just from curiosity: Why `Filling` does not support something similar?

Comment: @dimitris You can use the `PlotRange` to properly pan the region in the `RegionPlot`: 

`RegionPlot[2 x + 3 y < 6, {x, -3, 5}, {y, -3, 5},
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {-2, 4}},
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 Epilog -> Inset[Rotate[2 x + 3 y < 6, -35 Degree], {1.3, 1.4}]
 ]`

Comment: Perfect. Why you don't post it as a reply?

Comment: @dimitris. `Filling` does not support something similar; see my update.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Thanks for the update. All the workarounds are very useful.